# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "¡Vete a freír espárragos!"?

Tags: expresiones

¿Cuál es el origen de la siguiente expresión?

> ¡Vete a freír espárragos!

Sé que es una versión suavizada de *¡vete al diablo!* pero su origen no lo conozco.

Comment: En Argentina usamos *mandar a freír churros* con el mismo significado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

¡Interesante pregunta! Tampoco yo sabía el origen de esta expresión, así que buscándola encontré un blog la mar de interesante con una explicación bastante convincente:

**[Columna Zero - origen de la expresión vete a freír espárragos](http://columnazero.com/origen-de-la-expresion-vete-freir-esparragos/)**

> La frase vete a freír espárragos data del Siglo XIX, y se usaba con la
>   misma intención que actualmente. A sabiendas que el espárrago se cuece
>   en el primer hervor, la expresión hace referencia a la intención de
>   querer tener a alguien ocupado el mayor tiempo posible, y para ello y
>   evitar su molesta compañía, se le mandaba a freír espárragos. Por
>   aquel entonces también se decía “anda a esparragar”. Existe también la
>   teoría de que por aquella época los espárragos fritos no tenían
>   ninguna consideración culinaria, y por ende, realizar dicha tarea no
>   tenía ningún sentido más que perder el tiempo. Mandar a freír
>   espárragos con el intención de perder, al mandado, de vista.
>
> Con esa intención de echar a una persona de un lugar o apartarla del
>   trato con desaire, tras sus comentarios, inconclusiones o
>   impertinencias también se usan otras expresiones como “vete hacer
>   gárgaras”, “vete a freír churros”, “vete al carajo” o “vete a paseo”.
>   En Latinoamérica también se usa el dicho “vete a pelar/freír monos”.
>   Si bien es una expresión coloquial en términos informales con un trato
>   de desconsideración, suele usarse en entornos cercanos, aunque también
>   en desairadas discusiones como forma de concluirla.

El imprescindible blog 1de3 también tiene una entrada al respecto:

**[Mandar a uno a freír espárragos u otras cosas](http://www.1de3.es/2006/07/08/mandar-a-freir-esparragos/)**

> Son frases utilizadas para echar a una persona de un lugar o apartarla
>   del trato con desaire; cuando, hartos del fastidio que representa su
>   presencia o sus comentarios, nos deshacemos del indeseable de manera
>   desabrida.
>
> (...)
>
> Vete a freír espárragos es una frase documentada ya en el siglo XIX en
>   el que se decía anda a freír espárragos o anda a esparragar; esto es,
>   a coger espárragos. La expresión procede en última instancia del
>   proverbio latino Citius quam asparagi coquantur, ‘en lo que tardan en
>   cocer los espárragos’ en latín, y que hace referencia a un tiempo
>   brevísimo, ya que el espárrago debe ser retirado del fuego al primer
>   hervor. Entonces, si lo que se pretende es mantener ocupado el mayor
>   tiempo posible al individuo molesto, o se le manda a recogerlos o a
>   freírlos, en una confusión significativa enviando a freír algo que se
>   ha de hervir, en la línea de algo inútil como la del que asó la
>   manteca.

(Recomiendo leer el artículo entero por ser muy completo e interesante).

Así pues, con *vete a freír espárragos* se quiere decir o bien:

> - Vete a [hacer algo que lleva mucho tiempo], para así no verte en un buen rato.

o bien

> - Vete a [hacer algo inútil], para así no verte.

Comment: Buena respuesta, +1. En catalán también tenemos la expresión "engegar a fregir esparrecs", no se si traducida del español. Pero las páginas en catalán que he visitado coinciden con la primera cita. La solemos utilizar para deshacernos de alguien que nos esta incordiando o cuando no cede en una discusión (clásico en algunos bares :) ).