# Uso de "Mandar a mudar" en Hispanoamérica

Tags: diferencias-regionales, expresiones, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica

En su número musical "[Dilema de Amor (cumbia epistemológica)](https://youtu.be/bR7z69qdeDk)", perteneciente a su gira de 2010 "Lutherapia", el grupo cómico-musical *Les Luthiers* [canta](https://youtu.be/bR7z69qdeDk?t=309)

> La mandaste a mudar, la echaste sin piedad

Entiendo que mandar a alguien "a mudar" es como mandar a alguien a *tomar viento* o [*freír espárragos*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13415/1674).  [Mudar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PzX1swq%7CPzZoc6u) tiene el significado de "cambiar" (de ropa, lugar para vivir, etc.) o incluso "defecar", por lo que la expresión no es tan distinta de mandar a alguien lejos, a la mierda o a cagar.

Estas expresiones sí se usan en España, pero "mandar a mudar" no. No es que sea difícil entenderla con contexto, pero en España se favorecerían otras expresiones equivalentes. *Les Luthiers* es un grupo argentino. ¿Es "mandar a mudar" una expresión de uso común en toda Hispanoamérica o sólo en algunas regiones?

Comment: Buscando la expresión por ahí me encuentro con la siguiente letra: _Decías que me querías que nunca me podías dejar, sabías que estaba viviendo en la miseria total, hiciste la valija un día nena y te mandaste a mudar._ Visto así, no creo que uno se mande a sí mismo a la mierda. Creo que el equivalente español de mandar a alguien a mudar es "darle puertas" o "enseñarle la puerta de la calle" ("echarlo o despedirlo de casa"). Es decir, se debe entender "mudar" de forma literal: cambiar de domicilio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El diccionario de americanismos, en su entrada de *mandar* indica que:

> [**mandar(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=B7cvVglayx0AufKQvbZ)
>
> **~se a mudar**. loc. verb. Pa, Pe, Bo, Ch, Ar, Ur. Irse de un lugar repentina o inesperadamente. pop + cult → espon. (mandarse mudar).
>
> **~se mudar**. Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Ur. mandarse a mudar.

Lo que nos hace ver que *mandarse a mudar* se usa en Paraguay, Perú, Bolivia, Chile, Argentina e Uruguay, mientras que *mandarse mudar* (sin la preposición *a*) se usa en Ecuador, Perú, Bolivia, Chile y Uruguay.

Parece, pues, que se usa por todo el continente menos en Colombia y Venezuela. La leve diferencia en el uso de la preposición *a* o no daría para otra pregunta. Dado que en Bolivia, Chile, Perú y Uruguay se usan ambas, es fácil deducir que su uso es prácticamente indiferente.

Comment: Y averiguar lo que significa "pop + cult → espon." daría para otra pregunta también. :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo jajaja ya te digo. Yo deduzco _popular y cultismo, ambos porosos cual esponja_

Comment: [Ahí lo llevas.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20572/12637) :-)

Comment: Solo para confirmar lo ya dicho, en Colombia no se usa y sin contexto ni siquiera hubiera entendido el significado. Además recuerda que hispanoamérica continúa hacia el norte hasta México ;-)

Comment: @DGaleano gracias por la confirmación :) Y tienes razón, mencioné los países de Hispanoamérica que están en América del Sur. ¿Hay algún nombre para designarlos? Es decir, toda Sudamérica donde se habla español.

Comment: Lo que dijiste, "todo el continente," lo entendí bien como Sudamérica.  Nomás que la pregunta mencionó "toda Hispanoamérica." // Si quieres incluir Centroamérica, el Caribe y México: Latinoamérica.  Si quieres incluir el español hablado en EEUU, supongo que podrías decir "Las Américas."

Comment: @aparente001 el problema con [_Latinoamérica_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9rica_Latina) es que también incluye Brasil o Haití, pues hace referencia a los países de habla procedente del latín.

Comment: @fedorqui - "Latinoamérica": Muchas veces se podrá entender por el contexto.  Pero a los centroamericanos y los mexicanos no les gusta que se les excluya.