# ¿Qué quieren decir marcas como "pop.", "cult." y "espon." en el Diccionario de americanismos?

Tags: significado, abreviaturas, rae, asale

Si alguna vez has buscado términos en el *[Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=)*, habrás visto marcas que pueden llegar a parecer una ecuación, como la siguiente:

> pop + cult → espon.

Estas marcas y otras similares, ¿qué quieren decir?

Answer (score 5):

En un artículo titulado *[Repercusión del "Diccionario de americanismos" en el aula de español como segunda lengua](http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/24/24_035.pdf)*, escrito por Soraya Almansa Ibáñez, de la UNED, se puede leer lo siguiente (negritas mías):

> Otro de los grandes aciertos del DA es la inclusión de marcas sociolingüísticas y pragmáticas. La información sociolingüística se divide en cuatro tipos: registro específico (**carcelario, delicuencial, drogadicción, estudiantil, infantil, policial, prostitución**), valoración social de la voz en la comunidad de habla (**prestigioso, eufemístico, vulgar, tabú**), información sobre el parámetro estratificatorio —nivel sociocultural o sociolecto— (**culto, popular**) y estilo de lengua (**espontáneo, esmerado**). Respecto a las marcas pragmáticas, estas aportan datos sobre la intención comunicativa del hablante (**afectuoso, despectivo, festivo, hiperbólico, satírico**).

Más adelante, en una tabla se pueden comprobar cuáles son las abreviaturas, que hacen referencia a los listados resaltados:

> ```
> 12. Registro                        carc., drog., delinc., est., inf., polic., prost.
> 13. Valoración social               prest., euf., vulg., tabú
> 14. Estratificación sociocultural   pop., cult.
> 15. Estilo                          espon., esm. (precedidos de →)
> 16. Marcas pragmáticas              afec., desp., fest., hiper., sat., (precedidos y unidos por ^)
> ```

Por tanto, y por unir cada abreviatura con su significado, tenemos por orden alfabético:

```
^afec.   afectuoso
carc.    carcelario
cult.    culto
delinc.  delincuencial
^desp.   despectivo
drog.    drogadicción
→esm.    esmerado
→espon.  espontáneo
est.     estudiantil
euf.     eufemístico
^fest.   festivo
^hiper.  hiperbólico
inf.     infantil
polic.   policial
pop.     popular
prest.   prestigioso
prost.   prostitución
^sat.    satírico
vulg.    vulgar
tabú     tabú
```

Por tanto, la ecuación

> pop + cult → espon.

debe leerse como "aplica tanto a nivel popular como culto, y su estilo de lengua es espontáneo". Si nos encontráramos con

> pop ^ desp.

indicaría que el término "aplica solo a nivel popular (no culto), y expresa una intención despectiva".

Comment: ¿O sea que es culto, popular y espontáneo? No me queda claro si el `+` indica suma de casos o los combina de alguna otra forma. Ah, probablemente es la manera de unir elementos del mismo tipo, por lo que si fuera definido por ejemplo como afectuoso y festivo diríamos _afec. + fest._.

Comment: @fedorqui casi. El signo + aplica (entiendo) solo a los casos _pop._ y _cult._, cuando aplican ambos, referidos al nivel sociocultural del término. En el caso de las intenciones del hablante, se prefijan y concatenan con ^, por lo que tu ejemplo (ampliado) sería _pop. → espon. ^ afec. ^ fest._ Los casos _espon._ y _esm._ entiendo que son excluyentes y no se concatenan.