# ¿Qué es el "chamuyo" en la letra de Gotan Project que dice "no es chamuyo, es amor"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, argentina, letras-de-canciones

Estaba escuchando la espléndida [*Mi Confesión*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ4zObtAOuI) del grupo argentino Gotan Project. Ya iba por la tercera en bucle cuando recordé que siempre me sorprendió cómo acaba la primera parte de [la letra](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1747613):

> Si hablo de amor... sé que la extraño, de mis actos en vida soy dueño,
>   Pero me calla el dolor por el daño, y es como un sueño dentro de otro sueño.
>   Apuesto a pleno pero de callado, cada uno en la suya, yo ando rayado,
>   Sigo esperando sentado... que esta vez el destino no me deje plantado...no...
>   Que no me deje plantado... no nena.
>   Escúchame bien... no es **chamuyo**...es amor.

Esto de *chamuyo* nunca lo había oído, así que hoy me dio por buscarlo. El Diccionario de americanismos dice que:

> [**chamuyo**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=SpZ7m0svpx0ASqy3iX3).
>   I.  1.  m. Pe, Ch, Bo, Ar, Ur. Palabrería que tiene el propósito de impresionar o convencer. pop + cult → espon. (chamullo).
>   2.  Bo, Ar, Ur. Conversación susurrada o en voz baja. pop + cult → espon.
>   II. 1.  m. Ch, Ar. Acción o asunto de dudosa moralidad o legalidad. pop + cult → espon. (chamullo).

y después:

> [**chamullo**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=98S53oJYqx0ADhO7EpD).
>   I.  1.  Pe, Ch, Bo, Ar, Ur. chamuyo, palabrería que busca impresionar. pop + cult → espon.
>   II. 1.  Ar. chamuyo, asunto de dudosa moralidad. pop + cult → espon.
>   2.  Ch. Tejemaneje, enredo poco claro. pop + cult → espon.
>   3.  Ch. Mentira, especialmente la usada para justificarse. pop + cult → espon.

Dado que el grupo es de Argentina, me da la sensación que aplica la definición *Palabrería que tiene el propósito de impresionar o convencer*, algo así como [**farol**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HdnxIzT) (*4. m. Hecho o dicho jactancioso que carece de fundamento.* Marcarse, tirarse un farol). Sin embargo, tengo mis dudas sobre si es o no el caso.

¿Algún argentino podría dar su explicación al respecto, así como el contexto en el que se usa? Al fin y al cabo en el contexto de la canción se ve coloquial, pero el DAMER también menciona [*cult*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20572/1674).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Etimologias](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chamuyo):

> La palabra *chamuyo* es parte del argot lunfardo argentino y se refiere a la conversación que le hace un hombre a una mujer para llevarla a la cama, o la conversación trivial que hacen las personas para llenar huecos de silencio. La palabra *chamuyo* viene del verbo caló (dialecto de gitanos españoles) *chamullar*, donde significa "conversar".

[Wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chamuyar) (2.ª definición):

> Decir requiebros a otra persona con el propósito de seducirla.

Después de buscar entre *chamuyos* y piropos el *chamuyo* puede ser considerado a veces como un piropo "denso". Pero él lo que siente es amor...

Comment: "Chamuyo" tiene varias acepciones, todas en el espectro de contar algo no tan real, en mayor o menor medida (desde exagerar un poco las cosas para impresionar, hasta decir una mentira lisa y llana para no quedar mal ante alguien). En este caso creo que lo podés interpretar como "Te dije que te amo, y es verdad", o como "No te quiero impresionar para algo casual - te amo, y quiero algo serio".

Comment: Añadiría que *chamuyar* puede usarse como verbo pronominal transitivo cuyo objeto es la persona a la cual se trata de convencer; en este caso el significado tiene que ver invariablemente con lo sexual y no necesariamente implica engaño: *chamuyarse a alguien*.

Answer (score 1):

En Chile chamuyo/chamullo es un verbo coloquial y también un adjetivo. Por ejemplo, "chamullar" quiere decir: hablar con propiedad sobre algo que se está inventando en el momento, mintiendo con aplomo.

> Él está chamullando, no le hagas caso.

o bien:

> Él es un chamullento, no le hagas caso.

La RAE acepta [*chamullar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8WxTqlQ) para el uso amplio del español, pero para Uruguay y Argentina se precisa *chamuyar*.

> [**chamullar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8WxTqlQ)
>   Del caló *chamullar*.
>   1. intr. coloq. hablar.
>   2. intr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. chamuyar.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta Pablo! Nótese que [edité](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/20659/revisions) la respuesta para mejorar el formato. Por ejemplo, añadiendo dos espacios al final de una línea, se genera un salto de línea. De este modo, los bloques de citación se muestran correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Chamullo, chaya, tollo, es mentira, charlatanería, verso, artificio.

> Chamullento, ta adj. coloq. Chile. Que habitualmente utiliza expresiones confusas para desorientar a su interlocutor.

[chamullento — charlatán; mentiroso; cuentista; embaucador; cf. carrilero, engrupidor, pomadiento, chivero, chamullar, chamullo, chamullero; Ej: mira, si el huevón te gusta, bien; pero no le creas nada a los hombres, que son unos chamullentos incurables , no seas…](https://espanola.es-academic.com/25384/chamullento)

[Vender la pomada: Tratar de convencer de algo, generalmente una falsedad, a alguno(s).](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/vender_la_pomada)

Chamullo: (Chi fam) conseguir con camelos.

[Camelo: 1. m. Noticia falsa. 3. m. Simulación, fingimiento, apariencia engañosa. 4. m. coloq. galanteo.](https://dle.rae.es/camelo)

> Chamullo: Marcarse un farol, tirar un bolazo.

> Tirar un bolazo: mentira, engaño. Correr la bola.

> Cahuinear: Crear o propagar un chisme o situación confusa (cahuín).

> Marcarse un farol: (locución coloquial) Hacer una persona algo para deslumbrar a los demás o salir airosa al realizarlo.

> Tirarse un carril: (locución verbal) Decir algo, intentando adivinar o suponiendo, pero sin conocimiento ni base sólida.

> Chiva: Excusa.

> Tollo: Mentira, exageración.

> Confeti: 1. m. Conjunto de pedacitos de papel de varios colores, recortados en varias formas, que se arrojan las personas unas a otras en los días de carnaval y, en general, en cualquier otra celebración festiva.

> Chaya: 3. f. Chile. confeti.

> Chaya: Artificio. Ej: La ley aula segura no sirve, es sólo chaya para la galería.

> Charlatanería: 3. Arte de embaucar con un discurso entusiasta de aparente sensatez.

> Ej: Escúchame bien... no es chamuyo...es amor.

En el ejemplo podría reemplazarse chamuyo por verso.

> Ej: Escúchame bien... no es verso...es amor.