# ¿Qué quiere decir "en buenas cuentas"?

Tags: expresiones, chile

Ofrecí una recompensa (*bounty*) en Stack Overflow en español y surgió cierto debate porque quien había respondido era el propio autor de la pregunta. Surgió un debate y [un usuario chileno comentó](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78513/convenci%C3%B3n-de-nombres-en-php?noredirect=1#comment216248_78513):

> Cuando yo llegué a este sitio (había participado sólo en la versión gringa) no entendía la idea de hacer preguntas y autoresponderlas. **En buenas cuentas** no son realmente preguntas, son más bien como un hilo de discusión y reflexión. Esos votos negativos han de ser porque alguien dijo: "este señor se autoresponde para ganar más puntaje".

El debate daría mucho de sí *stackoverflowísticamente*, pero centrémonos en el lingüístico: ¿qué quiere decir ***en buenas cuentas***? Parece una forma de resumir algo, pero nunca lo había oído.

Consultado el autor, [me comenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78513/convenci%C3%B3n-de-nombres-en-php?noredirect=1#comment217070_78513):

> al menos en Chile "en buenas cuentas" significa "en el fondo" o "en otras palabras".

Esto en España lo diríamos como "al fin y al cabo" o "a fin de cuentas", pero así nunca lo oí. Entonces las preguntas son: ¿es esta una expresión puramente chilena? ¿se usa en algún lugar más, como los limítrofes Argentina, Perú o Bolivia?

Comment: A mi me parece una versión de algo como "teniendo las cuentas claras..." que vendría a significar "resumiendo" o "al fin y al cabo", tipo "hacemos las cuentas y al final nos queda XYZ".

Comment: Yo diría: al final de cuentas. Nunca oí "en buenas cuentas".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta se encuentra en el *[Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cuenta)*:

> **en buena cuenta.** loc. adv. Pe. En resumen, en conclusión. [pop + cult → espon.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20572/12637)
>   **en buenas cuentas.** loc. adv. Bo, Ch. En resumen, en conclusión. pop + cult → espon.

Así pues, parece que además de en Chile se usa en Bolivia, y la misma expresión pero con las palabras en singular se usa en Perú.